# Enclosing hidden input file in a link in an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work, and I'm stuck. I need to display a link in a Bootstrap dropdown, this link would trigger a file selector. On file selection, I would then upload the file to my server.

So I've created a directive to enclose my upload link : this directive contains a label for the input file, and the input file itself, which is hidden. When I click the label, the file selector is supposed to show up. Alright. But this behaviour doesn't happen when I'm enclosing my directive in a `a` tag... and that's precisely what I intended to do.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating this behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/pabuisson/2gzczhgk/4/

If anybody has any clue about why it fails inside a link tag, or how I could fix this, I'd be glad to hear about it. I'm quite new to the AngularJS-Bootstrap mix, so I may have missed something obvious.

Thanks a lot for your help guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just doesn't work in html, even without angular. As a test I created a page with just a link and an input inside of it like so:

```
<a>CLICK ME TO PICK A FILE<input type='file'/></a>
```

And it doesn't function like how you want.

**Jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/1cbzbhp3/

**EDIT**
So it looks like the javascript for opening/closing the dropdown was firing the close event before the file open dialog event could fire. You can get around this with a quick extra line of code or 5:

```
    link: function(scope, element){
        element.bind("click", function(event){
           event.stopPropagation(); 
        });
    }
```

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/2gzczhgk/5/

Comment: If you look carefully, that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm doing a ``<label>Blah<input type='file'/></label>``, which perfectly works in HTML. And I'd just like to enclose this whole thing into a link. Otherwise I'll just have to duplicate Bootstrap styles for my own element, but I'd rather not to.